# How do I add all urls on page to an array, in xcode?

Tags: xcode, url, hyperlink, webkit, count

I load a webpage (containing some hyperlinks) into a webview in xcode, is there a way I can count and keep track of these links?

Can I add all the hyperlinks to an array, so that each link as an index. Or is there already a parameter I can access that will allow me to navigate to a link by its index on the page?

ie, can I say "n = 12. Count the links on the page. Navigate to the nth link" -- for example?

Many thanks!

Vince.

Comment: Please add the specific platform, you are developing for. The answer given below targets iOS, but should be fine for cocoa desktop apps as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can get all a tags included in a webview's page by:

```
NSString *allTags = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('a');"];
```

But you might iterating by JavaScript through all links, getting their url. You get the number of tags by:

```
NSString *noOfTags = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('a').length;"];
```

You can access a tag index based by:

```
int i = 0; // index of tag you want to access
NSString *aTag = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('a')[%@];", i]];
```

Finally, you may direct a webview to a certain URL by:

```
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:myURLString]]];
```